# Using lpsolve in R setup

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I'm attempting to solve a optimization problem made up of three groups. one or zero choices may be made from each group, but at least one choice must be made. The biggest complicating factor is that values change as multiple groups are selected. Following an example i have come up with the code below. It appears to be designed for LP-solve IDE. However, it will not run do to a unspecified "syntax error". Preferably, this would be run in R but the formerly mentioned IDE , version number 5.5.2.5, is also installed.

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

DesignFlood = 0.93
#alt[1] = coastal protection [ft] , alt[2] = additional inland flooding, 
#alt[3] = costs for each alternitive in order of 1A,1B,1C,2A,2B,3A,3B [BILLION DOLLARS]
Alt_1A = c(11, 2, 5.0)
Alt_1B = c(8, 0, 0.416)
Alt_1C = c(15, 5, 6.3)
Alt_2A = c(11, 5, 2.8)
Alt_2B = c(12, 6, 13.1)
Alt_3A = c(8, 2, 7.2)
Alt_3B = c(10, 1, 9.1)
####costs for each alternitive in order of 1A,1B,1C,2A,2B,3A,3B [BILLION DOLLARS]
####ALTCOST = c(5.0, 0.416, 6.3, 2.8, 13.1, 7.2, 9.1)
#Cost for inland flood mitigation per [ft]
INLANDCOST = 0.050




/* Objective function */
  min: +Alt_1A[pick_1A*3] + Alt_1B[pick_1B*3] + Alt_1C[pick_1C*3] + 
            Alt_2A[pick_2A*3] + Alt_2B[pick_2B*3] + Alt_3A[pick_3A*3] + 
                Alt_3B[pick_3B*3] + inlandMit;

/* Constraints */
OneX_1: +pick_1A +pick_1B +pick_1C <= 1;
OneX_2: +pick_2A +pick_2B <= 1;
OneX_4: +pick_3A +pick_3B <= 1;
OneX_5: max(Alt_1A[pick_1A],Alt_1B[pick_1B],Alt_1C[pick_1C],
            Alt_2A[pick_2A],Alt_2B[pick_2B],Alt_3A[pick_3A],
            Alt_3B[pick_3B]) + AddProtect >= DesignFlood;
OneX_6: if(pick_1A == 1 |  pick_1B == 1 |  pick_1C == 1 & pick_2A == 1 | Alt_2B == 1 ){
                AddProtect = 4
}else if (pick_1A == 1 |  pick_1B == 1 |  pick_1C == 1 & pick_3A == 1 | Alt_3B == 1 ){
  AddProtect = 4
}else if (pick_2A == 1 | Alt_2B == 1 & pick_3A == 1 | Alt_3B == 1){
  AddProtect = 4
} else if(pick_1A == 1 |  pick_1B == 1 |  pick_1C == 1 & pick_2A == 1 | Alt_2B == 1 & 
                                                            pick_3A == 1 | Alt_3B == 1){
          AddProtect = 6
} else {
          AddProtect = 0
        };       
OneX_7:  max(Alt_1A[pick_1A*2],Alt_1B[pick_1B*2],Alt_1C[pick_1C*2],
             Alt_2A[pick_2A*2],Alt_2B[pick_2B*2],Alt_3A[pick_3A*2],
             Alt_3B[pick_3B*2])*INLANDCOST = inlandMit;


/* Variable bounds */
pick_1A <= 1;
pick_1B <= 1;
pick_1C <= 1;
pick_2A <= 1;
pick_2B <= 1;
pick_3A <= 1;
pick_3B <= 1;
```

Comment: Now i am not entirely sure, as i am a bit unfamiliar with the `lpSolveAPI` package, this does not directly seem to be related to the package, as it does not use the methods described in the package [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolveAPI/lpSolveAPI.pdf). The notation is not standard R notation either. For example `OneX_1: ----` is not valid `R` notation, and this is likely where your error is occuring. While this is a valid programming problem, i suggest reading the documentation first and rewrite your problem using the documented functions.

Comment: You are mixing R syntax with LP File syntax.